# Is there a Perl 6 equivalent of a byte array?

Tags: arrays, raku

Let's take a Java example of `byte[] data`. In a method signature for Perl, I can do `method myMethod($data)` but this is a form of dynamic typing which is useful.

However, I wish to manipulate an array of bytes - So is there a preferred way to transform data types into a byte array or something remotely similar?

I have looked around, and have seen this code here to transform source data into a byte array:

```
my $arr =  Buf.new('mystring'.encode('utf-8')); 
say $arr;
```

Would this just be the preferred input into my method(s) that will manipulate the `Buf` through the `$data` method variable?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question. Do you mean something like `sub foo ($data) { $data[1] = 0x99 }; my $bar = Buf.new: 'mystring'.encode: 'utf-8'; say $bar; #\`[Buf:0x<6d 79 73 74 72 69 6e 67>]; foo $bar; say $bar; #\`[Buf:0x<6d 99 73 74 72 69 6e 67>]`?

Comment: @raiph I think so, I aim to do operations such as `$data[offset + x] & 0xff`

Comment: Well, I imagine you mean [`+&`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/+&), so `$data[offset + x] +& 0xff`, but yeah, that'll be fine. You can add a `Buf` type to the signature if you want to tighten the typecheck: `sub foo (Buf $data) ...`. Maybe try these things out and then write an answer to your own question (which is a legit thing to do on SO). I'm headed off to bed to sleep. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about the question, but is this what you're looking for?

```
my int8 @a = ^10;         # a native array of 8-bit signed bytes
sub frobnicate(int8 @b) { # a sub taking a native 8-bit array
    dd @b;
}
frobnicate @a;
# array[int8].new(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this is helpful:

```
my \buffer = Buf.new: 'mystring'.encode: 'utf-8';
my \offset = 3;
my \mask   = 0x03;

sub mask-buffer-from-to (\mask,
                         \buffer,
                         \from = 0,
                         \to = buffer.end) {
  buffer[from..to]».&{ $_ +&= mask }
}
mask-buffer-from-to mask, buffer, offset;
say buffer; # Buf:0x<6d 79 73 00 02 01 02 03>
```

I've slashed sigils (used `\` in variable declarations instead of `$` etc.) to reduce clutter (slashing sigils means they're dropped after the declaration). My hope is that this makes it easier to read. Please let me know if that worked for you or if it actually made it harder.

The `= 0` and `= buffer.end` bits in the sub's signature are defaults.

If you were reasonably familiar with P6 it would be obvious what the `».&{ $_ +&= mask }` expression meant. But you're not, so I'll explain it.

Reading it in English, it means that, given the range of buffer elements on the left, iterate (in parallel if the compiler wishes to do so) over each element, bit-wise AND-ing each element with `mask`.

Reading it in computerese, in detail:

```
»
```

is a [hyperoperator](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/%3C%3C.html), the P6 distillation of [SPMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPMD).

`»` iterates the operand on its left (the left operand corresponds to the MD bit of SPMD) and applies the operation on its right (corresponding to the SP bit of SPMD) on each iteration.

Only use `»` if the SP and MD operands are SPMD safe, i.e. the individual operations don't interfere with each other. (If you're not sure, use something like a `for` loop or `map` instead.) In this case it's hopefully obvious to you that the operation (bitwise AND-ing each element with a mask) is SPMD safe.

To remember what this use of `»` does, just remember that it's a SPMD op and/or note how it shows two parallel `>` (to remind you it assumes parallel semantics, i.e. the compiler is free to parallelize it) with the leftside greater than the right side (to remind you that the left operand is a plural thing, i.e. it can and typically does have multiple elements, whereas the right is always just a single operation).

```
.
```

This is the method call operator. It calls the method on its right given the invocant on its left.

```
&
```

`&` immediately after a `.` forces the expression on the right of the `&` to be interpreted as a routine.

```
{ ... }
```

Braced code immediately after `.&` is interpreted as a closure (a routine). Inside the closure, `$_` (which may be read as "this one") is aliased to each of the elements resulting from iterating the operand to the left of the `».&`.

```
$_ +&= mask
```

This line is of the form `LHS op= RHS`. This form is shorthand for `LHS = LHS op RHS`. So the code in the closure is shorthand for:

```
$_ = $_ +& mask
```

i.e. "this one becomes this one bit-wise AND masked with mask".

I apologize to readers who find this answer confusing; please leave comments below and I will react accordingly, perhaps writing a completely different, simpler, new answer. My hope is that @madcrazydrumma finds it interesting and helpful.

Comment: Why the slashed style for someone learning the language? For something more constant/enum like I can understand why you might want to use it. But the clutter is both the same and also logically a lot more obscure and misleading in this example. If I came across some Perl 6 where it was all like this I would be fairly disgruntled maintaining it to say the least. Sigils are an unavoidable part of the language if someone doesn't like them they need to find a different language to use. Avoiding them just because you can for no reason is odd to say the least.

Comment: Thoughts, @madcrazydrumma? **1** I disagree about the clutter. Sigils *can* bring *clarity*. But when they don't, slashing them *reduces* visual and cognitive clutter. **2** I found `buffer[from..to]».&{ $_ +&= mask }` easier to read than `$buffer[$from..$to]».&{ $_ +&= $mask }` and thought OP would too. **3** I thought Java style identifiers would be friendlier for OP. **4** I find it visually & cognitively much simpler to reason about code if sigils are *significant* -- which implies eliminating them when they are noise. **5** I consider the latter, not sigils per se, to be a P6 strength.

Comment: @MattOates, I'm currently awaiting your response to my reply to you and madcrazy's feedback before deciding on how to edit my answer to try incorporate your view. I think it's important to expose those learning P6 to sigil slashing but accept the particular usage of it in this answer is arguably inappropriate. It's important to me that I feel you understand my 5 points or have at least documented the effort to do so in commentary that readers can view. Otherwise I'd be inclined to leave my answer as is. Of course you may not care if I make an edit but I'd still appreciate open minded feedback.

Comment: I just wrote a response https://gist.github.com/MattOates/3bb818947552ed3917eb3739fdd02c12 thats too long by 889 characters. But suffice to say I have a difference of opinion with almost all of your points. But its your answer, I wouldn't change it. My comment stands as the addendum with another POV, my intent wasn't to pressure you into altering your answer. A plurality of voice is surely better.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. I don't feel pressured. I'm open minded. I like to take on differing points of view and incorporate it into our future. I'm going to read what you've written, respond with a reply at the gist page, and sleep on it. @madcrazydrumma, if you see this, what are your thoughts?